# SOIC-8 package in KiCAD

Tags: datasheet, kicad, packages, soic

I want to incorporate a chip in my design.
This is the datasheet:
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809251831_Diodes-Incorporated-AZ34063UMTR-G1_C99659.pdf

It is an 8 pin SOIC package.

[image]

When I try to assign a footprint for this package in KiCad, I am introduced with many choices:

[image]

I am not sure which one to select, and neither do I know how to actually find the one I want. I am not sure what these numbers mean,  or how to export that information from the datasheet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the [datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809251831_Diodes-Incorporated-AZ34063UMTR-G1_C99659.pdf), we see a drawing of the required package on page 12:

[image: Package Dimensions]

Here we can see the body of the part is 4.7-5.1mm long (nominal 4.9mm), and 3.8-4.0mm wide (nominal 3.9mm). The pin pitch is 1.27mm.

This suggests you should use one of the parts labelled "3.9x4.9mmxP1.27mm"

The acronym "EP" usually refers to some sort of thermal pad. Your chip does not have one, so you can ignore all of the packages labelled EP.

According to @Hearth from the comments, "N7" indicates the footprint is missing pin 7. As such we can exclude that footprint.

That leaves package number 114 in your list as likely a good option.

I would still have a look the packages in the library and compare it to the datasheet to make sure it is correct.

Comment: N7 means there's no pin in position number 7, a common layout for certain devices.

Comment: @Hearth Makes sense.

Comment: For KiCad specifically, there's a set encoding for the information that goes in footprint names, which is defined in the [KLC](https://klc.kicad.org/). It's a working document that's subject to change, and there may be a handful of footprints left over from before it was instated that haven't been renamed yet, but if you're confused by what something means you can check there.

Comment: (although i believe there's a section where you can add any additional necessary information that the KLC doesn't have a set way of encoding, so it might not get everything. But hopefully that information is relatively easy to understand, since it's meant to stand alone without a set encoding.)