# KiCad - SOD-323 footprint

Tags: pcb-design, diodes, kicad, footprint

I want to use this component in my design:
https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2201121330_JSMSEMI-1N5819WS-S4_C2927280.pdf

It says that the footprint is `SOD-323`.
I couldn't find this footprint in KiCAD's library.

Is this footprint available, or do I have to create it myself?

Comment: A variant of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/669777/soic-8-package-in-kicad

Comment: A variant of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/669777/soic-8-package-in-kicad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's available under the name "D_SOD-323".

[image]

Note: The pad size of the recommanded footprint from the datasheet is even bigger than the hand soldering variant from KiCAD. If you want to follow the datasheet, you'll have to create your own footprint. Personally, I think the pads in the datasheet are comically large and would use the KiCAD footprints.

Comment: Thanks! Do you propose i use the Standard, or the HandSoldering version?

Comment: @user1584421 For soldering with a soldering iron, I would use the hand soldering version. The normal version is very small and can be frustrating to work with, especially if your hands are not steady.

Comment: I intend to use an assembly service. Therefore I am not interested in soldering it by hand. I just asked because the HandSoldering version seems longer. I am afraid that the footprint will be smaller that the actual device (according to its datasheet at least). I have never heard of a datasheet with having wrong dimensions.

Comment: @user1584421 Change the footprint to the dimensions from the datasheet, look at it in the 3D viewer and you will see what I mean by "comically" large. I've used the standard footprint before for home reflow soldered PCBs and it worked fine (sucks for re-working though).

Comment: OK, Thanks, I will stick to KiCad's footprint (NOT the HandSoldering one).

Comment: @user1584421 I looked at a couple of different SOD323 datasheets and found most to be in between the normal KiCAD and the hand soldering one. The most in depth footprint I found [here](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/package-information/SOD323.pdf). Here the footprint is bigger if wave soldering is used. I haven't used wave soldering myself, but if you use it I would follow that datasheet.

Comment: It's an SMD assembly service.... With that in mind, would you suggest I use the HandSoldering one or the regular one?